# What's wrong with my Boost Phoenix lambda?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-phoenix

I consider that Phoenix lambda functions is somehow C++11 lambda. So I try the following:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38f1a2b655ea70fc

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace phoenix;
using namespace arg_names;
using namespace local_names;


struct FakeOne{
    int field;    
};

int main()
{
    auto k = FakeOne();    

    auto fn = (lambda(_a=k)[_a.field ]);
   cout <<
      fn()
   << endl;

}
```

Which throws:

```
main.cpp:20:32: error: 'const _a_type' has no member named 'field'
     auto fn = (lambda(_a=k)[_a.field ]);
```

Comment: *"I consider that Phoenix lambda functions is somehow C++11 lambda"* No they aren't. They use placeholders to substitute values and generate expressions. But they are not a language extension, so note what the compiler says: The placeholder `_a` has no member `field`, which makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Manu343726 I pass `k` to lambda in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just invoke members on placeholders (like _a) since they don't declare the members (like `field`). Instead, bind them:

```
auto fn = phx::bind(&FakeOne::field, k);
```

**Update** To the comment:

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using namespace phx::local_names;

struct FakeOne{
    int field;    
};

auto k = FakeOne { 3 };

int main()
{
    auto fn = phx::bind(&FakeOne::field, k);

    k.field = 99;
    return fn();
}
```

Compiles down to

```
main:                     ; test.cpp:13
    movl    k(%rip), %eax ; boost/boost/proto/expr.hpp:65
    movl    $99, k(%rip)  ; test.cpp:16
    ret
```

on GCC -O3

Comment: Does bind make some overhead?

Comment: At compile time, yes. A decent compiler should inline that with optimization enabled

Comment: @tower120 I've added a self contained sample with disassembly for your enjoyment